# puts statements for debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, logging

When I code, I make quite intense use of "puts" statements for debugging. It allows me to see what happens in the server.

When the code is debugged, I use to remove these "puts" statements for I don't know what reason.

Is it a good idea or should I leave them instead to give more clarity to my server logs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the logger instead of `puts`. Use this kind of statements:

```
Rails.logger.debug "DEBUG: #{self.inspect} #{caller(0).first}" if Rails.logger.debug?
```

If you want to see the debugging in the real-time (almost), just use the `tail` command in another terminal window:

```
tail -F log/development.log | grep DEBUG
```

Then you do not need to remove these statements in production, and they will not degrade performance too much, because `if logger.debug?` will prevent the (possibly expensive) construction of the message string.

Using standard output for debugging is usually a bad practice. In cases you need such debug, use the diagnostic `STDERR`, as in:

```
STDERR.puts "DEBUG: xyzzy"
```

Most of the classes in Rails (models, controllers and views) have the method `logger`, so if possible use it instead of the full `Rails.logger`. 
If you are using older versions of Rails, use the constant `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` instead of `Rails.logger`.

Comment: Thx, I need to have a closer look at the logger apparently... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

use the logger : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Answer (score 1):

I use the [rails_dt](https://github.com/dadooda/rails_dt) gem designed specifically to make such kind of debugging easier.

Using `Rails.logger` or `puts` directly is somewhat cumbersome, since it requires you to put a lot of decorative stuff (`DEBUG`, `***` etc.) around debug messages to make them different from regular, *useful* messages.

Also, it's often difficult to find and defuse the debug output generated by `Rails.logger` or `puts` if the message doesn't appear to contain enough searchable characters.

`rails_dt` prints the origin (file, line), so finding the position in code is easy. Also, you will never confuse `DT.p` with anything, it clearly does debug output and nothing else.

Example:

```
DT.p "Hello, world!"

# Sent to console, Rails log, dedicated log and Web page, if configured.
[DT app/controllers/root_controller.rb:3] Hello, world!
```

Gem is available [here](https://github.com/dadooda/rails_dt).